# How to use a <link> referring back to another .css file in HTML

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to link my HTML file to a CSS file in order to use the spans I created on the CSS file.

I am coding this with the Komodo application. So every time I run the HTML file in a browser it is all black text with no background. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the content of my files.

**Logan_Tucker_Style_Sheet.css** and **Logan_Tucker_Page_With_Link.html**

```css
span.firstlinewordone {
  background: lime;
  color: red
}

span.firstlinewordtwo {
  background: #00FF00;
  color: #FF0000
}

span.firstlinewordthree {
  background: rgb(00, 255, 00);
  color: rgb(255, 00, 00)
}

span.secondlinewordone {
  background: lime;
  color: blue
}

span.secondlinewordtwo {
  background: #00FF00;
  color: #0000FF
}

span.secondlinewordthree {
  background: rgb(00, 255, 00);
  color: rgb(00, 00, 255)
}

span.thirdlinewordone {
  background: lime;
  color: aqua
}

span.thirdlinewordtwo {
  background: #00FF00;
  color: #00FFFF
}

span.thirdlinewordthree {
  background: rgb(00, 255, 00);
  color: rgb(00, 255, 255)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
  <title> Using Custom Colors </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Logan_Tucker_Style_Sheet.css">
</head>

<body>
  <span class="firstlinewordone">
    One
  </span>

  <span class="firstlinewordtwo">
    Two
  </span>

  <span class="firstlinewordthree">
    Three
  </span>

  <br>

  <span class="secondlinewordone">
    One
  </span>

  <span class="secondlinewordtwo">
    Two
  </span>

  <span class="secondlinewordthree">
    Three
  </span>

  <br>

  <span class="thirdlinewordone">
      One
  </span>

  <span class="thirdlinewordtwo">
    Two
  </span>

  <span class="thirdlinewordthree">
    Three
  </span>

  <br>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your HTML file does not see CSS file. Please try following steps:

- Right click on element and choose Inspect Element option. Developer panel should appear, allowing you to see which style applied to selected element
- Check browser console for any errors. Especially for Not Found errors. Those will show where your browser search for linked file.
- Open HTML code in browser's Inspector, locate link tag and try to open file in new page. If everything is fine, CSS file's content should appear.
- Clear browser's cache on page refresh. In Windows you can do so by pressing `Ctrl + F5`
- If nothing helps, something outside is wrong. As you can see, there is nothing wrong in provided code itself, because it renders correctly on this page.

Answer (score 0):

Html and css files are in the same folder? 
If css is placed somewhere else you should direct link to it eg. Css/example.css .

Also you don't need to use span.classname in css, try to use without span, just .classname.

Comment: It did not fix the problem, I still have regular text displaying on my browser.